# How to render image over video in react native using FFMPEG

Tags: react-native, image, video, ffmpeg

I'm working on an app that let users to create stories like on instagram.
Now to save the text, drawing and other stuffs over the video I've used react-native-shot and I took a shot of these objects than save it in .png or .jpg format.
By using ffmpeg I want to overlay the screenshot over the video, to create the story.
I can perform this activity both on frontend or backend, and even if on the backend it's easier, due to the flexibility of python, I think it's better to perform the rendering operation directly on react-native, so the best, and unique, library to achieve it is ffmpeg.

**1. Here's my command that actually works if I run on mac terminal, but it doesn't if I run it on react native:**

```
launchImageLibrary({ mediaType: "mixed", selectionLimit: 0 }).then(
      ({ assets }) => {
        const photo_uri = assets[0].uri
        const video_uri = assets[1].uri

        FFmpegKit.executeAsync(
          `ffmpeg -i ${video_uri} -i ${photo_uri} -b:v 1M \
          -filter_complex '[1:v]scale=354:640 [ovrl], \
          [0:v][ovrl]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2' output.mp4`,
          async (session) => {
          }
        );
      }
    );
```

**2. Here's the classic uri's format of sources took from user local library:**

IMAGE => file///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D33390AF-14EF-4231-9F00-6FC8FB2B6ACD/tmp/29EA60A3-93C1-4116-B9E9-FFF5FEE05197.jpg

VIDEO => file///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D33390AF-14EF-4231-9F00-6FC8FB2B6ACD/tmp/d910dd91-3cf3-484a-b2c4-4272cfbe60ef.mp4

**3. Here's the output error:**

Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ffmpeg'
ffmpeg: Invalid argument

The strangest thing is that running the ffmpeg command on mac terminal, as already said, it actually works but with react-native not.
Maybe the error is related to the uris formats or some manipulations with filesystem are necessary.

What's my error? Is there an alternative solution? Is it better to render image-overlay-video on the backend?

Thank you

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?